# Spring MVC, access list index in a hardcoded way without using <c:forEach>

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Here is my code snippet which adds an arraylist to model attribute

```
 List<ViewBillResult> viewResult = viewBillBusiness.searchViewBill(stBillId);
        model.addAttribute("viewResult", viewResult);
```

I have accessed each BillSearchResult attribute's on jsp page as follows

```
<c:forEach var="viewLis" varStatus = "number" items="${viewResult}" >
<tr >

      <td><form:hidden  path="viewList[${number.index}].billNo"/></td>
       </tr>
 </c:forEach>
```

How can i access the first index of `searchResult` array without using forEach(I want to access `viewResult.get(0).billNo` )

Answer (score 1):

You could use `${viewResult[0].billNo}`

Answer (score 0):

Like here :

```
<td><form:hidden  path="<%= viewResult.get(0).billNo %>"/></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you want to access it. If you want to just read it use the solution by Reimeus. If you want to write into the first element and your appended code works then use : 
`<form:hidden  path="viewResult[0].billNo"/>`